# "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" - occur when taking time difference of two date

Tags: oracle11g

Following query causes the error ORA-01858:

```
   SELECT 24*(to_date(EndDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss PM')- to_date(StartDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss PM')) diff_hours  FROM TESTRESULT
    WHERE TestNo='0000714625' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL AND StartDate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Are `StartDate` and `EndDate` of type `date`?  Or `varchar2`?

Comment: @Justin Cave StartDate and EndDate are date type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `to_date` on `date` columns.  `to_date` does not actually accept a `date` as a parameter, it just accepts a `varchar2`.  If you try to pass a `date` to `to_date`, Oracle has to perform an implicit conversion to cast the date to a `varchar2`.  That will use the session's `nls_date_format`.  If that differs from the format mask that you pass in to `to_date`, it is very likely that you will either get an error or you will get a result that is incorrect.

Just subtract the two `date` columns to get a difference in hours

```
SELECT 24* (EndDate - StartDate)
  ...
```